# What is the best way to capture a screenshot from a udp stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, ubuntu-14.04, screenshot, live-streaming

I'm trying to capture a screenshot from a udp stream using ffmpeg in a Ubuntu 14.04 System.
Following is the command

```
ffmpeg -y -i udp_ip -vframes 1 -q:v 1 test.png
```

But the image captured is of very poor resolution and I observed a lag while taking the screenshot.

Please suggest a best tool or a way to take a screenshot in the fastest way and also of the best image resolution possible.

**edit:**
log files

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab --enable-libwavpack --enable-nvenc
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[mpeg2video @ 0x390cc60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 7 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx':
  Duration: N/A, start: 144.130744, bitrate: 4128 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Program-1   
      service_provider: Encoder 
    Stream #0:0[0x42]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 4000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x43]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'player.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 png
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=1 speed=0.729x    
video:777kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: PNG should be lossless. No quality loss. Share full log.

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya...added logs.But is ffmpeg the fastest way to capture a lossless image or can I consider any other tool as well?

Comment: Seems ok. Are you referring to the aspect ratio?

Comment: Try to generate N frames (selecting only where there was a scene change) to see if it's something from your source. `ffmpeg  bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4 -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.8)" -frames:v 10 -vsync vfr -y out%02d.jpg`

Comment: @Mulvya,yes referring aspect ration.

Comment: Thanks @leandromoreira. i'll try your code and update here.

Answer (score 1):

Since, this seems to be an issue of aspect ratio, and not  quality, per se, use

```
ffmpeg -y -i udp_ip -vf scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1 -vframes 1 -q:v 1 test.png
```

The scale filter rescales the video to square pixels. The SAR filter isn't strictly necessary but in case the PNG muxer writes that data, better to reset it.

Comment: Thanks...I'll try this.Is there a way to capture the screenshot fast?As it takes few seconds to capture the screen,and since we are using screen capture in multiple places in the code and in all scripts,so the overall time taken for running all the scripts is too much.Is ffmpeg the best tool or can you suggest anything better than this?Thank you for your reply.**edit:** able to get the desired aspect ration, but there is no improvement in, the time to grab the shot.

Comment: For a streaming input, ffmpeg can't get faster.

Comment: This works as written, but the connection to the UDP stream remains and FFMPEG doesn't exit.  Is there anything I can add to make sure FFMPEG exits upon creation of the image?

Comment: FFmpeg should close the connection. How are you checking? You can try adding `-t 0.1`  before `-i udp_ip`